# Loading a page in div using jquery and ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to open content into a div on click, I can't figure out where I am going wrong any help is much appriciate. Thank you
**Html:**

```
    <li><a id="hrefid" href="#link">Link</a></li> 

<div id="content"> </div>
```

**Jquery:**

```
$('#hrefid').on('click', function (e) {
    var load = $(e.target).attr("href");
    if(load == "#link") {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: "/page/test/272.html",
            complete: function (event) {
                $("#content").contents().remove();
                $("#content").append(event.responseText);
            }
        });
    }
    });
```

Comment: Why are you using `complete` rather than `success`? Or you could use `.done()` as per the examples in [the doco](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

Comment: What's your question really, what part doesn't work as expected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your intended operation is a `GET` operation as far as i understand, so instead of `type: 'post'` make it `type: 'get'`

Comment: I was able to get it working by making the switch thank you! any idea on how I can pass a "id" from <a> tag to the ajax url to attach it at the end of it?

Comment: Glad to help, please accept the answer if you are happy with it. for your other question you can have a data attribute on the anchor tag and get it using $(this).data('id') on the click event then concat it to the url.

Comment: Thank you so much ! I was able to get it working. I am dynamically loading multiple links with different data-ids and with same <a>, ajax call only works on the first link any suggestion on how I can get it to with all the links ?

Comment: You should ask a separate question with the right details, not sure at this point.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! just posted it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38237301/open-multiple-dynamic-links-with-the-same-ajax-call

Answer (score 0):

jquery `load` will be much better option, try the following code

```
$('#hrefid').on('click', function (e) {
    var load = $(e.target).attr("href");
    if(load == "#link") {
        $( "#content" ).load( "/page/test/272.html", function() {
             //anything after load is complete
         });
    }
});
```