# Open multiple dynamic links with the same ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am displaying multiple dynamic links which use the same , ajaxloads the content on the first link fine but doesn't work for the rest of them. How can I get it to load the content of other links in the same div?

**Html:**

```
$string .= '<a id="hrefid" data-id="'.$name["id"].'" href="link" >'.$name["name"].'</a>'.
<div id="content"> </div>
```

**Jquery:**

```
$('#hrefid').on('click', function (e) {
    var load = $(e.target).attr("href");
    if(load == "#link") {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: "/page/test/"+id,
            complete: function (event) {
                $("#content").contents().remove();
                $("#content").append(event.responseText);
            }
        });
    }
    });
```

Comment: Try using success instead of complete. Or have you already tried that?

Comment: I tried it, when i use success it doesn't even load the content of one link that is working

Comment: Strange... what is the value of event.responseText? (with complete, not with success)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the id to a class, remove # from the if statement

```
$string .= '<a class="hrefid" data-id="'.$name["id"].'" href="link" >'.$name["name"].'</a>'.
<div class="content"> </div>

$('.hrefid').on('click', function (e) {
    var el = $(this);
    var load = $(e.target).attr("href");
    if(load == "link") {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: "/page/test/"+id,
            success: function (event) {
                el.next().empty();
                el.next().append(event.responseText);
            }
        });
    }
    });
```